# Let recv() only the previous accepted socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I am using this server application:

[image]

I'd like to add some conditions to `FD_ISSET()` before `recv()`:

```
if (`client's socket` was the previous `accepted socket`) {
    canRecv = TRUE;
} else {
    canRecv = FALSE;
}
```

This is my idea of ​​program functionality:

1. `recv` only from the previous `accepted socket`
2. Wait for the communication to end
3. FD_CLR()

I don't know how to:

1. loop through each **fd** from `select()`
2. let only one `recv()`
3. return the others to the queue of `select()`

I use simple example from IBM Knowledge Center:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzab6/xnonblock.htm

Comment: Why? What's wrong with all the previously accepted sockets, that are all still connected, that you refuse to receive from them? When are they ever going to get serviced? If you're not interested in them why not close them? What is the outer problem here?

Comment: And if you want to ignore a socket for reading in the select loop, just leave it out of the read FD_SET.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `std::vector<int> sockets;` to keep your sockets. Checking if it's the latest you added will then be done by just checking `if(current_socket == sockets[sockets.size()-1]) ...`

Here's an example with a helper class to keep a list of your sockets and function for waiting on activity.

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

constexpr unsigned other_socket    = 0b00;
constexpr unsigned server_socket   = 0b01;
constexpr unsigned latest_addition = 0b10;

class SocketList {
public:
    explicit SocketList(int server) : readfds{} { add(server); }

    void add(int s) {
        sockets.push_back(s);
        FD_SET(s, &readfds);
        if(s > max_fd) max_fd = s;
    }

    // return the ready sockets and a state for each
    std::vector<std::pair<int, unsigned>> wait() {
        int ready_sockets;
        do {
            ready_sockets = select(max_fd + 1, &readfds, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
        } while(ready_sockets == -1 && errno == EINTR); // retry if interrupted

        // throw if an error occured
        if(ready_sockets == -1) throw std::runtime_error(std::strerror(errno));

        std::vector<std::pair<int, unsigned>> result;

        // loop through each fd used in the select()
        for(int s : sockets) {
            if(FD_ISSET(s, &readfds)) {
                auto x = other_socket;

                if(s == sockets[0]) x |= server_socket;
                if(s == sockets[sockets.size() - 1]) x |= latest_addition;

                result.emplace_back(s, x);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

private:
    int max_fd = 0;
    fd_set readfds;
    std::vector<int> sockets;
};
```

It can be used like this:

```
    int server = socket(...);

    SocketList ss(server);

    // all sockets in result are ready
    auto result = ss.wait();

    for(auto [sock, state] : result) {
        if(state & server_socket) {
            // do server things on sock
        } else if(state & latest_addition) {
            // do stuff if sock was the latest addition
        } else {
            // do this if sock is not the server socket or the latest addition
        }
    }
```

> 1. `recv` only from the previous `accepted socket`
> 2. Wait for the communication to end
> 3. FD_CLR()

For that you really don't need select. Just `recv` directly on the previously accepted socket. This is usually not a good behavior of a server that is supposed to server many clients simultaneously since a bad client could connect without sending anything, and that would stop the server from responding to any new clients - until the bad client decides to disconnect (if that ever happens).

> I don't know how to:
>   1. loop through each **fd** from `select()`

That is shown in the code above.

> 2. let only one `recv()`

When you have the `result` vector in the example above, you can loop through them and only keep the part dealing with `latest_addition`:

```
        if(state & latest_addition) {
            // do stuff if sock was the latest addition
        }
```

> 3. return the others to the queue of `select()`

The state of the other ready sockets in `result` will remain unchanged if you don't read from them, so they are returned automatically. This also means that the next `select` will return immediately if you don't read from all `fd`s that are ready, so the program will spin really fast until there's some action on the latest added socket again, effectively making this a polling program and the `select` is sort of useless.

Comment: Note that `(e)poll()` is more efficient than `select()`, in part because `(e)poll()` tells you exactly which sockets actually satisfied the wait, rather than you having to hunt for them manually like with `select()`. And also because `select()` is limited in the number of sockets it can monitor at a time, whereas `(e)poll()` has no such limit.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, but it didn't specify Linux and BSD has `kqueue` instead of `epoll`.